# how to upgrade laravel 6 to 7

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-6

i am trying to upgrade laravel 6 to 7, i got an error.

```
 our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
 packages.

   Problem 1
     - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.0.3
     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
     - laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/console ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[7.x-dev, v7.0.0],
 laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
     - laravel/ui v2.0.0 requires illuminate/console ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[7.x-dev, v7.0.0],
 laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
     - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v6.0.3].
     - don't install illuminate/console 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
     - don't install illuminate/console v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
     - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.0.3, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.0.3].
     - Installation request for laravel/ui ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[2.x-dev, v2.0.0].
```

Comment: check this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Comment: Of course the _Upgrade Guide_ is the de facto place to learn about what's changed. But I'll humbly suggest [Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) as an answer for _how to upgrade Laravel_.

Answer (score 13):

Just follow the documentation, you must have installed **php7.2.5**

> Update your laravel/framework dependency to ^7.0 in your composer.json
> file.
>
> In addition, update your nunomaduro/collision dependency to
> ^4.1,
>
> phpunit/phpunit dependency to ^8.5,
>
> facade/ignition to> `^2.0

After that as next step.

The report and render methods of your application's `App\Exceptions\Handler` class should accept instances of the **Throwable** interface instead of Exception instances:

```
use Throwable; // add this line

public function report(Throwable $exception); // replace Exception with Throwable
public function render($request, Throwable $exception); // replace Exception with Throwable
```

after that run

```
composer update
```

Comment: This worked for me upgrading V6.20 to 7.30

Comment: This works. From V6 to V7. Two things I may add to this solution is. 1. Add Laravel UI. `composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"`. 2. Optional, modify your composer to use either php 7 or 8. add this line to composer.json `"php": "^7.2.5|^8.0"`

Answer (score 3):

Update The following packages

```
"nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",

"laravel/ui": "^2.0",

"facade/ignition": "^2.0",

"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
```

for More clarity go to [Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade)

If Handle.php file error Check out [Solution](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31686)

Comment: i added ignition to my composer then edit handle and it worked for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per Laravel Documentation to upgrade from `laravel 6` to `laravel 7`

> Update your `laravel/framework` dependency to `^7.0` in your `composer.json`
>   file. In addition, update your `nunomaduro/collision` dependency to
>   `^4.1`, `phpunit/phpunit` dependency to `^8.5`, and `facade/ignition` to `^2.0.

and then run composer update in your terminal

```
composer update
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7.2.5 is required for laravel 7.0. Check the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

If you are get problems with this make sure you read ahead to this section and make the required changes.  I found I HAD to make the changes in composer.json to get it to work.  From the command line it just kept getting in a twist:

> Authentication
>
> Scaffolding
>   Likelihood Of Impact: High
>
> All authentication scaffolding has been moved to the laravel/ui repository. If you are using Laravel's authentication scaffolding, you should install the ^2.0 release of this package and the package should be installed in all environments. If you were previously including this package in the require-dev portion of your application's composer.json file, you should move it to the require section:
>
> composer require laravel/ui "^2.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below link having video/instructions to upgrade your Laravel 6 project to Laravel 7 :-

https://youtu.be/8gyAkicohsU

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an existing code and it was like this on version 5.8 in `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
 public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

I changed `use Exception;` to `use Throwable;` and made this change

```
 public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

and it worked after changing every `Exception` to `Throwable` and updating all dependencies and language versions.